# Confusion about how to look up t value for margin of error in confidence intervals

Tags: self-study, t-confidence-interval

I have been given the formula for a confidence interval on a gaussian distribution with unknown variance as 
$\bar{x} \pm t_{\frac{\alpha}{2},n-1} \frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}$

And I am wondering which column to use in the [T table](https://www.ttable.org/) for a 95% CI.
[image: T-Table]

I suspect it must be $t_{.995}$ here

But am wondering how to reconcile the notation with the $t_{.025}$ implied by the formula I have been given. ( I am thinking $\alpha$ would be .05 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of describing this:

- A $95\%$  confidence corresponds to a probability of $1-\alpha = 0.95$ of the specified interval covering the parameter
- which corresponds to a probability of $\alpha=0.05$ of a $t$-distributed random variable being outside the interval,
- and here you want two tails, so by symmetry a probability of $\frac \alpha 2 = 0.025$ of being in the upper tail
- with a probability of $1-\frac \alpha 2=0.975$ of being below the upper point of the desired interval

You want the corresponding column labelled cum.prob $t_{.975}$ or one-tail $0.025$ or two-tails $0.05$

Comment: Thank you . I was missing the cum.prob.