# Should the formula for test statistic have an absolute value?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-distribution

I have been given a formula for calculating a t test statistic as

$$t_{n-1} = \frac{ \bar{x}- \mu_0}{\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}} $$

Where $\bar{x}$ is the sample mean, $\mu_0$ is the hypothetical true mean, $S$ is the sample standard deviation and $n$ is the sample count.

But when I plug my values in, the outcome is negative.

I don't see how to look up a negative value on the T-table.
Should I be taking the absolute value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [a previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/604052/confusion-about-how-to-look-up-t-value-for-margin-of-error-in-confidence-interva) you were looking at [image: T-Table]

and wanted the column labelled cum.prob $t_{.975}$ or one-tail $0.025$ or two-tails $0.05$

If the table had been extended to the left, then by the symmetry of the $t$ distribution,

- there would have been a column labelled cum.prob $t_{.025}$ or one-tail $0.025$ or two-tails $0.05$
- and it would have had the values $-12.71, -4.303,-3.182,\ldots$

and similarly with the other columns.

Doing this would double the size of the table without adding useful information beyond the change of signs.

Answer (score 1):

The [support](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) of $\mathrm t$ distribution is $\mathbb R. $ So, it is still a legit case if $t_{n-1}<0.$ And don't forget the probability curve is symmetric about $0.$

Comment: Thank you, but then how do I look up the value using https://www.ttable.org/ ?

Comment: As Mewbacca comprehensively wrote, it depends on what you are testing. As for how to use a table, hint __symmetry__.

Comment: Thank you, but the formula I have been given does not ask what I am testing. I can just plug in the null-hypothetical mean . So is the formula missing something?

Comment: @Kirsten, check Henry's [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/604239/362671) which I hope would clear your impending confusion. This is again symmetry at work.

Answer (score 1):

As User1865345 states, the t statistic can take negative or positive values.

Your reference to the table depends on your hypotheses. The common null hypothesis is $H_0: \mu = \mu_0$. The alternative hypotheses can be one sided ($H_1: \mu \le \mu_0$ or $H_1: \mu \ge \mu_0$) or two sided ($H_1: \mu \neq \mu_0$).

For a one-sided alternative $H_1: \mu \ge \mu_0$, at a level of significance $\alpha$, you reject $H_0$ if the calculated value, $t_{calc}$(without taking absolute value) is greater than $t_{n-1, \alpha}$ from the [table](https://www.dummies.com/wp-content/uploads/451675.image0.jpg).

For a one-sided alternative $H_1: \mu \le \mu_0$, at a level of significance $\alpha$, you reject $H_0$ if the calculated value, $t_{calc}$(without taking absolute value) is lesser than $-t_{n-1, \alpha}$ from the [table](https://www.dummies.com/wp-content/uploads/451675.image0.jpg). (Again, as pointed out, the t distribution is symmetric about the t = 0 and the left tail probability at level of significance $\alpha$ is $-t_{n-1, \alpha}$)

For a two-sided alternative $H_1: \mu \neq \mu_0$, the tail probability or the rejection region is split into two halves, and you reject $H_0$ if the calculated value, $|t_{calc}|$ is greater than $t_{n-1, \alpha/2}$ from the [table](https://www.dummies.com/wp-content/uploads/451675.image0.jpg). (Note the absolute value and $\alpha/2$).

It's best to remember your alternatives, visualize the graph of the distribution for critical region, and glance at the table before concluding the test.